# Authorizing mobile API call in iOS

Tags: ios, api, security, mobile

I am looking for some nice solution to protect a 'sign-up' mobile API call against frauds, e.g. creating new users by spam bots.

One possible solution it to put secret API token in the mobile app binary. It is reasonably safe if we pre-encrypt the API token, enable SSL-pinning and (in iOS) protect app with PT_DENY_ATTACH flag against debugger attack.

Another solution is using captcha to eliminate non-human clients.

Both above solutions have cons and pros. Android developers are proud of their Google token - they can send it within API call so called server could verify caller identity with the aid from Google. I wonder if there is any similar mechanism in iOS? Does someone know even better solution?